# jQuery draggable/droppable miss event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I want to handle an event when my draggable item was dropped but not inside my droppable item. So far I could get only this far:

```
 $('#myDraggable').draggable({
  stop: function (event, ui) {
      if (event.srcElement.id != 'myDroppable'){
         // Missed
      }
  }
 });
```

But the problem is that I'm chaning `#myDroppable` element when something is added to it. So next time I drop something to it `event.srcElement.id` may not be `myDroppable`, but any id of its new children. I could add an overlay on top, but when there is a scrollbar it gets more complicated. Is there another way to handle this event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($(event.srcElement).parents().andSelf().has("#myDroppable").length === 0)
```

Take your element, Grab it's entire parent chain add the current element then reduce it to the set matching "#myDroppable". If it's length is 0 then your not dropping it into your droppable.

I'm not to certain with that plugin but normally `this === event.srcElement`

[.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) [.andSelf](http://api.jquery.com/andself/) [.has](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

Comment: it's weird, but `event.srcElement` cannot be converted to a jQuery object, it becomes null after `$(event.srcElement)` however its type is `HTMLElementDiv` in my case. Also I was looking for more efficient way of doing that, checking for every element in the container doesn't look like a good solution.